# When/where does the mysql NOT FOUND handler get triggered

Tags: mysql, cursor

Today I've been cracking my head to find out why a piece of code in my procedure didn't work. The procedure basically looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `updateSomeStuff`()
begin


DECLARE updateSomeStuff_done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE updateSomeStuff_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT 
    sport
  FROM staging.ssa_SomeStuff_sports
  where SomeStuff_id = p_id;

<1. a bunch of statements and procedure calls>

OPEN updateSomeStuff_cursor;
  read_loop1: LOOP
    FETCH updateSomeStuff_cursor INTO
l_sport;
    IF updateSomeStuff_done = 1 THEN
      LEAVE read_loop1;
    END IF;

    <Do some handling for each record>

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE updateSomeStuff_cursor;

end
```

The problem I had was that te code that should have been executed in the cursor loop didn't get executed. After some investigation, I found out that the variable updateSomeStuff_done was already set to 1 before getting to the loop, so the loop was immediately abandoned.

I was able to solve the issue by setting updateSomeStuff_done back to 0 just before the loop, but now I am wondering what actions could cause the variable to be set to 1. The actual piece of code that triggered the action is a call to another procedure, apparently the NOT FOUND handler I declared is not just a local variable, which puzzles me...

Anyone who can explain me whey this is happening?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and can't find an answer,were you able to solve it?

Comment: I've solved it by (re)setting updateSomeStuff_done to 0 right before the loop, but I'm still curious as to why mysql is changing it in the first time.